# Paging all results in servicestack ormlite

Tags: c#, paging, ormlite-servicestack

Is there any way to page the results of an Ormlite query that retrieves all results. From another post on here, I have found the following:

```
var result = db.Select<Group>( q => q.Where(predicate).Limit(skip:5, rows:10 ));
```

However, I'd like to query without the 'Where' clause. When omitting this bit of code, the Limit method is no longer available. So effectively, what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
var result = db.Select<Group>().Limit(skip:5, rows:10);
```

Maybe Select isn't the correct method to retrieve all the records?

Answer (score 5):

`db.Select<T>` works the same way and executes a SELECT against the specified table, however if you want to execute a custom Query on the server you'll need to provide the query as done in your first example:

```
var result = db.Select<Group>(q => q.Where(predicate).Limit(skip:5, rows:10));
```

Which can also be rewritten as:

```
var q = db.From<Group>();
db.Select(q.Where(predicate).Limit(skip:5, rows:10));
```

When you don't supply a Query your executing a SELECT all against the table, e.g:

```
db.Select<Group>()
```

Already executes the query and returns all rows in the `Group` table.

If you want to limit it you'll still need to provide the query, e.g:

```
db.Select<Group>(q => q.Limit(skip:5, rows:10));
```

Or:

```
db.Select(db.From<Group>().Limit(skip:5, rows:10));
```

### [Paging in AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#service-clients-support)

Also since you're looking to paginate queries you should look at the [automatic support for paging in AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#paging-and-ordering) which includes typed Service Client support, e.g:

```
client.Get(new QueryRockstars { Skip=10, Take=20, OrderBy="Id" });
```

As well as providing a [typed streaming API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#service-clients-support) with `GetLazy<T>` which transparently executes multiple paged queries behind the scenes:

```
var top250 = client.GetLazy(new QueryMovies { 
    Ratings = new[]{ "G", "PG-13" } 
})
.Take(250)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

As i know, you cannot do it without where, but you can set where like "id is not null" or something like that.

Also, you can use builder  :

```
QueryBuilder<MyDataObject, String> builder = myDao.queryBuilder();
builder.limit(10);
builder.orderBy("columnName", true)  // true for ascending, false    for     descending
List<MyDataObject> list = myDao.query(builder.prepare());  // returns list of ten items
```

Comment: This does not answer the question on how to do this with [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite).